# Is there something like SESAME for OWL

Tags: rdf, owl, sesame

Sesame is for RDF, so if I want to use OWL is there anythin?

Comment: What exactly do you need? Do you need a storage, a parser, and inference engine? If all you need is the data, OWL is RDF too.

Answer (score 5):

Jena is a triple-centric API.  If you want something actually geared towards OWL, you should try the [OWLAPI](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [OWLIM](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim), which is an OWL reasoner compatible with Sesame.

Answer (score 2):

Sesame ought to be ok for OWL. If you need a friendlier api try jena, which is fairly similar, but provides an OWL 'view' of the RDF via the [Ontology api](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ontology/).

For example:

```
RDFNode myClass = model.get("http://example.com/ont#MyClass");
OntClass theClass = myClass.as(OntClass.class); // view rdf via Ontology api
theClass.listInstances(); // returns iterator over instances
theClass.addDisjointWith(otherClass);
```

Jena also supports OWL inferencing using a rule engine, or via pellet.

Comment: also, [ONT_API](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-api/wiki/Examples) (OWL-API over Apache Jena) might be interesting more. Apache Jena Ontology api is only for OWL1, while ONT-API meets OWL2-specification + supports structural (axiomatic) view from OWL-API

Answer (score 1):

I believe Sesame supports only RDF Schema inferencing out of the box. If you want to use OWL inferencing with Sesame you might need to use an external inferencer for it and also decide what level and version of OWL you need.

[OWL 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-features/)

- List item
- OWL Lite
- OWL DL (Description Logic)
- OWL Full

[OWL 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles)

- OWL 2 EL
- OWL 2 QL
- OWL 2 RL

Answer (score 1):

You can also want to have a look at a Sesame extension which provides custom rule-based reasoning support using SeRQL. Please see [this blog](http://jeenbroekstra.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/simple-rules-using-construct-queries-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

Protege Owl Api is probably for OWL like sesame is for rdf